# Guiding to a different UI through Hyperlink

Tags: java, gwt, hyperlink

I am trying to create a GWT application with a hyperlink which serves the navigation into diverse user interfaces of the same application. I use the class Hyperlink and I define the links as :

```
Hyperlink yearViewLink = new Hyperlink("YearView","yearView");
```

for exapmle. I cannot figure out of the documentation, what exactly the second parameter of the above constructor should be. A class that implements the HistoryListener? How does generally the "pointing" by a HyperLink function?

Answer (score 1):

The second argument is the history token. It is actually a string. So when you click on the hyperlink, it fires an history event. In your HistoryListener implementation, you can use this token to decide which page should be shown to the user. See the documentation of [Hyperlink](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html). See how it is used in [GWT showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwHyperlink).

Thanks,
Ganesh